# Mirth Connect: Failed to start channel_Failed to start HTTP Listener

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I'm fairly new to using Mirth Connect. The Mirth Connect Administrator dashboard opens up, but the status of the channel is stopped. When starting it an ERROR occurs that says Failed to start channel XYZ and Failed to start HTTP Listener. I want to get my channel to successfully start and looking help with any solutions to doing this. Any suggestions?

Below is the error that occurs:

```
[2017-12-07 11:45:54,951]  ERROR (com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ErrorTaskHandler:25): com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.StartException: Failed to start channel XYZ (27355de6-a).

at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.start(Channel.java:716)

at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DonkeyEngineController$DeployTask.doDeploy(DonkeyEngineController.java:1838)

at com.mirth.connect.server.controllers.DonkeyEngineController$DeployTask.execute(DonkeyEngineController.java:1731)

at com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ChannelTask.call(ChannelTask.java:67)

at com.mirth.connect.server.channel.ChannelTask.call(ChannelTask.java:16)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.ConnectorTaskException: Failed to start HTTP Listener

```
at com.mirth.connect.connectors.http.HttpReceiver.onStart(HttpReceiver.java:301)

at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.SourceConnector.start(SourceConnector.java:104)

at com.mirth.connect.donkey.server.channel.Channel.start(Channel.java:692)

... 8 more
```

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

```
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)

at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)

at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)

at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:317)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:235)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)

at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401)

at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)

at com.mirth.connect.connectors.http.HttpReceiver.onStart(HttpReceiver.java:297)

... 10 more
```

I want to get the status of the channel to successfully start and deploy.

Currently, that status of the channel is Stopped.

Comment: Answered my own question. I rebooted my system and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your case, but the default HTTP listening port is 80. If you are running mirth over a linux system ports below 1024 are not available to regular users.

At least from my experience, binding and permission denied error are usually related to low ports.

Try using a higher port and let us know if that was the cause of the problem.